# How can I get my Python script to run from my dotnet core windows service?

Tags: python, c#, .net-core, microservices, ironpython

A bit of background,

- I have a **dotnet windows service** that needs some data from a Python script (main.py)
- **main.py**, which uses multiple modules including numpy, scipy and other 3rd party modules,
  is responsible for doing some logic calculations which currently are impossible to be done in C#
- **main.py** accepts few parameters and return some results which they are then consumed by our **dotnet windows service**.
- I am using Python v3.8

Now, I am struggling to come up with a solution to have both dotnet windows service and python script to work together. There are suggestions to use *IronPython* but I believe it has limitation on importing 3rd party modules which might not work in this scenario.

I was thinking of using this **main.py** as a **microservice** ie a restful API using Flask probably by doing this my **dotnet windows service** will can make requests whenever it needs the python script to carry out the calculations, and it's scalable when it comes to using it elsewhere

Otherwise please advice if you believe this can be done differently

I would love and welcome any suggestions, recommendations or questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironpython is compatible with Python 2.7. Python3 support is a long way off. If you are using numpy and scipy, I'd definitely go the microservice route so that you can be using current, supported versions.

So now that your C# is calling a REST API does the python service need to run on Windows?  Can you run on a linux box or Windows running WSL?

Comment: I haven't looked into the implications/limitations as yet. As it stands, the suggested microservice will run on Windows, the same box alongside the dotnet windows service mentioned above. Is there anything I should look out for? Thanks @WombatPM

Comment: If you are not in production, I'd install Apache or NGINX and avoid IIS to run the microservice.

Comment: and if I am in production? what would you suggest in this case?

Comment: That depends on the Operations team, assuming you have one.  Ops teams with standard monitoring, logging, and reporting typically want services on Widows boxes to run under IIS.  If you don't have such a requirement then you are free to do as you please.  I ran an internal only API using Apache and a desktop box for many years.

Answer (score 0):

Add SOmething like this method:

```
     public class YourClass
        {
            public string Run(string cmd, string args)
            {
                ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                start.FileName = "python";
                start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", cmd, args);
                start.UseShellExecute = false;// Do not use OS shell
                start.CreateNoWindow = true; // We don't need new window
                start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
                start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
                using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                    {
                        string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
                        string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }

}
```

And then, call your python file there like below:

```
var res = new YourClass().Run("your_python_file.py","params");
 Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: Referring to the example above and assuming the script in your_python_file.py needs some 3rd party modules to function. How to go about importing 3rd party modules? Should your_python_file.py run on a specific environment? I would've thought that the modules should be installed beforehand and prior to running your_python_file.py. Thanks Abdus